# How can I remove an element from an array at an index position without permanently changing the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How do I remove an item from an array at a specific index without permanently removing the item from the array?  I have

```
my_data_col.tap{|i| i.delete_at(index)}.select{|item| ... }
```

I notice that, after the call, `my_data` contains one element fewer than it did when I started.  How do I remove the element at the index without permanently altering the array?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense - you want to remove an item from an array, but not remove it from the array? If you want to delete the item, the array will be shorter. If you want the item to go away, but reserve the spot at the index, then set the item at that index to null or 0

Comment: I just want to remove the item before I apply the "select" statement to it.  I would like it to remain after that entire line is executed.

Comment: why not just `dup` the `Array` e.g. `my_data_col.dup.tap{#...etc,etc,etc}`

Comment: There is no "permanent removing" vs. "temporal removing". You probably meant "removing from the receiver" vs. "creating a new array without the element".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example in @Ursus's post (now deleted) I would execute as follows:

```
my_data_col.select.with_index do |str,idx| 
  str.respond_to?(:downcase) && idx != index
end.map(&:downcase).uniq
```

Next time please post your full example so people can assist more easily